# Mongo DB search by condition priority

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql, angular11

I am performing a search on the collection based on different columns. Basically what I need is that when I search, the name starting with the keyword entered should appear on top of the list, and then other names from different columns that contain the keyword should appear.

I am having a hard time finding direct functionality in MongoDB to perform this operation.
Any logic is appreciated.

example :

```
[
  { name : Pro1},
  { name : testpro},
  { name : Pro2},
  { name : testpro2}
]


so when I query on this array with the keyword **Pro** the expected output should be :

[ Pro1,Pro2,testpro,testpro2]


so that all the names starting with the exact keyword should appear first then the list of names containing the keyword should be there.
```

Comment: give an example if you can, with sample data and expected output, in valid json text, looks like you need regex match but i am not sure

Comment: added an edit including the example, I am already using regex but I am confused as to how to maintain two queries in an optimized way or something. !! @Takis